# Multiple Logs messages in Test

Tags: robotframework

I have a script like below:

```
[CCO-XXXXX_4] 
         [Tags]    TEST_CCO-XXXXX 
         Run Keyword And Continue On Failure        Run Test      General                test.out         testProfile          mode.out 
         Run Keyword And Continue On Failure        Run Test      General                test.out         testProfile          mode.out
```

The Idea is to run 2 test cases with different arguments:

```
Run Test
    [Documentation]    Run the suite
    [Arguments]       ${type}     ${profile}     ${file}    ${test}
    When suite config is updated 
    Then publish test status

Then publish test status
    Set Test Message     ${LogStr}

Stop Test  
    [Documentation]    Stop Execution of suite
    [Arguments]       ${FIALUREMSG}        
    Log To Console    ${FIALUREMSG}
    Fail        ${FIALUREMSG}
```

The issue is in the report - when the test fails for both the runs then there are 2 separate individual messages in [image: Error Report]report messages: "This is stop called"

But when it passes only one message log is available - since there are two runs for the above two test cases is it not possible that the for each individual test there can be test related message : [ex "Hello this an example" should be logged twice?]

[image: Successs Report]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that [Set Test Message](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Test%20Message) overrides the earlier content in every iterations. To fix the problem you should use the `append` parameter of this keyword. For example:

```
Set Test Message    is continued.   append=yes
```

Relevant part from the documentation:

> If the optional append argument is given a true value (see Boolean arguments), the given message is added after the possible earlier message by joining the messages with a space.

Comment: Thanks it works but it comes in same line - is there a way it can be logged with new lines also?

Comment: @Programmer I suggest putting a `\n` at the end of your messages as the separator character cannot be overridden. E.g.: `Set Test Message     ${LogStr}\n`